# Fantasy Manga/manhwa where MC is dropped into a world where he has to survive in the wild

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga that I have read a few years back. It is a manga where the MC is dropped into a world where he has to survive by himself in a forest. He learnt to find food, build shelter and tame the wild. He built a house and started planting different crops and dug his own irrigation system which he explained why and how in the manga. He also tamed wolves/dogs and spiders monsters which he uses to set up an alarm system for his house. Eventually he discovered cat girls, elves, fallen angel/harpy girls and sheltered them in his house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for *[Isekai Nonbiri Nouka (Farming life in another world)](https://myanimelist.net/manga/110087/Isekai_Nonbiri_Nouka)* by Yasumo, Naitou, and Kinosuke.

> Having died of sickness at the age of 39, Machio Hiraku is given the opportunity to go to another world. When asked what his wish is by God intending to give him strength, he requests to have a healthy body, offered a second wish, he chooses to live peacefully, a third wish to be able to know the local language, and for a final wish, to be able to be a farmer.

The spiders and wolves you mentioned.

[image: Spider and wolves]